# Build contingency table in Java

Tags: java

I have a Scoreboard of a football league.
I want to rank every team.
To do that I want to compare every match to every Team and put the results into a matrix.

Which is the best Collection to do so ? I tried ArrayList but I was disappointed!

An example of ScoreBoard:

```
TEAM1|  SCORE | TEAM2 | SCORE
AAAA |   20   | BBBB  | 10
AAAA |   12   | CCCC  | 14
BBBB |   1    | AAAA  | 2
```

I want to build a Matrix like this one, too:   Any help ? any instuction ? Any tip will help!

```
       AAAA        BBBB       CCCC
AAAA   0           abs(2-1)   0     
BBBB   abs(20-10)  0          0
CCCC   abs(12-14)  0          0
```

I forgot to say that I have a Class ScoreBoard
with variables

```
String name1,name2;
double score1,score2;
```

Comment: Don't hurt the `ArrayList`'s feelings. What did it do to dissapoint you? PS: use a `class` to group data.

Comment: Use custom Comparator(s) to sort your List (or other Collection)?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I forgot to say that I have alread a class.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is it a Question ? I haven't custom comperators. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: That is an interface. You can use it to control the "sort ordering" in your Collection.

Comment: Yes, I  know that Interface. but I can not understand where it can be help me. My thinking was:  To have a List  or Set my Scoreboard, and I need to create a 2-dimension Array to store my data. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Use an array or whatever kind of `List` of game result objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use both classes and comparators for this.

```
public class ScoreBoard implements Comparator<ScoreBoard>{
  String team1, team2;
  double team1_score, team2_score;

  @Override
  public int compare(ScoreBoard s1, ScoreBoard s2) {
    //Sort anyway you wish in here
    return Math.abs(s1.team1_score - s1.team2_score) - Math.abs(s2.team1_score - s2.team2_score);
  }

  public void createAndSort() {
    List<ScoreBoard> boards = new LinkedList<ScoreBoard>();
    //...
    //boards.add(....);
    Collections.sort(boards, this);
  }
}
```

Usage, Populate a list of ScoreBoards and store them in a List. As for you matrix, i'm not sure i understand what you mean by

> I want to build a Matrix like this one...

Answer (score -1):

i created a program for ur problem run and comment (give suggestions please)

My program

```
import java.util.*;
class Matches
{
static LinkedList MatchesList = new LinkedList(); 
public void addMatches(ScoreBoard SBtemp)
{
  MatchesList.add(SBtemp); 
  }
public LinkedList getMatches()
{
 return MatchesList;   
}
}
class ScoreBoard 
{
ScoreBoard(String name1,String name2,Double score1,Double score2)
{
     Matches addmat=new Matches();
     this.name1=name1;
     this.name2=name2;
     this.score1=score1;
     this.score2=score2;
     this.diff=Math.abs(this.score1-this.score2);  
     addmat.addMatches(this);
}

String name1,name2;
Double score1,score2,diff;
}
public class Mycode{
 public static void main(String []args){
     ScoreBoard SB1=new ScoreBoard("AAAA","BBBB",20.0,10.0); 
     ScoreBoard SB2=new ScoreBoard("AAAA","CCCC",12.0,14.0); 
     ScoreBoard SB3=new ScoreBoard("BBBB","AAAA",1.0,2.0); 
     //default value for matrix
     Double Matrix[][]=new Double[3][3]; 
     for(int n=0;n<3;n++)
     for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
     Matrix[m][n]=0.0;
Matches dismat=new Matches();
LinkedList MatchesList = new LinkedList(); 
MatchesList=dismat.getMatches();
      //create matrix
int m=0,n=0;
           for(Iterator i = MatchesList.iterator();i.hasNext();)
  {
     ScoreBoard SBtemp2 = (ScoreBoard)i.next(); 

     if(SBtemp2.name1.equals("AAAA"))
     {
         m=0;
         if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("BBBB"))
         {
             n=1;
             Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }
         else if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("CCCC"))
         {
         n=2;
          Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }  
     }

     if(SBtemp2.name1.equals("BBBB"))
     {
         m=1;
         if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("AAAA"))
         {
             n=0;
             Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }
         else if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("CCCC"))
         {
         n=2;
          Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }   
     }

     if(SBtemp2.name1.equals("CCCC"))
     {
         m=2;
         if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("BBBB"))
         {
             n=1;
             Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }
         else if(SBtemp2.name2.equals("AAAA"))
         {
         n=0;
          Matrix[m][n]=SBtemp2.diff;
         }
     }

     }

  // Print matrix
  for(n=0;n<3;n++)
 {
  for(m=0;m<3;m++)
       System.out.print(Matrix[m][n]+" ");
        System.out.println(" ");
  }
 }

}
```